# Windows DNS migrating Start of Authority SoA to Server 2016

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, internal-dns

I'm migrating DNS servers from 2008 to 2016.  I've already added the DNS role to the 2016 servers, and they're successfully servicing requests.  However, my DNS 
Unfortunately, all of the documentation I see regarding changing SoA is for older Windows Server versions, and not from Microsoft.  Where can I find definitive instructions?

I know Windows has been moving to decentralized model with Domain Controllers and other functions, but if there's no such thing as SoA anymore, it would be reassuring to see that stated officially.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You added the DNS role. Did you create a zone? If so, what type? Primary, Secondary, stub?

Comment: No changes to zones.  The new server is replicating the existing servers that I intend to decommission.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you're replicating the existing servers then you have to have zones. I'm assuming that you have Secondary Zones created on the new server? If not, then create them, transfer them from the Primary Server, then change them from Secondary to Primary when you're ready to cut over. That will make the new server the SOA for the zones.